# How do I install an older version of an app on an iPhone?

Tags: ios-appstore, iphone, ios, trello

I want to install the [Trello App](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/trello-organize-anything/id461504587?mt=8) on my iPhone. On the phone I have iOS 7. When I try to install the App, it tells me it needs at least version 8 of iOS.

I do not want to upgrade my iOS version, especially for the sole purpose of installing an App. However, I do want to use it, it's kind of important.

I searched for a while about how to do this, but I could only find solutions that would work if you installed the App before and it shows up on the "Purchases" page in iTunes or something like that. And this doesn't apply to this case.

---

How can I install an older version of the App (one that requires "only" iOS 7) without having to upgrade the operating system on my iPhone ?

Comment: Probably not without jail breaking unless you have a full iPhone backup with an older copy of the app, or the old app in iTunes.

Answer (score 10):

It sounds like the [Apple Support article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201377) explains what you need to do to get the app in the version you want.

- Go to the App Store on your **iPhone**.
- Press Updates and then press Purchased.
- When you get there, it should show your Apple account and it will say
  My Purchases.
- Press that and it will show you all of your apps
- Find Trello and try to download it. If a version of the app that is compatible with your version of iOS is available on the App Store, it will let you download it to your phone.
- If the version is not available, go to the iTunes App Store, find the app and click Ratings and Reviews.
- There is a button there that says App Support. Click that and then put in a query to the developer. They may be able to let you directly download the version of the app that you need from them.

If all of this fails, possibly other options like Todoist have the older version of their app that you can access.

This is unfortunately not going to help you with this app, as it does not sound like you had downloaded this app prior to this question, but it will help you in the event that you accidentally upgrade an app that will then no longer work with your version of iOS.

1. Go to iTunes and Delete the new version of the App from your library and also from your drive.
2. Go to the Music>iTunes>iTunes Media>Mobile Applications folder on your drive.
3. In that folder will be all of the current apps plus a folder called Previous Mobile Applications.
4. Previous Mobile Applications stores all of the old versions of your Apps each time you do an update through iTunes.
5. Find the version of the App that works with your version of iOS and drag and drop it onto iTunes. iTunes will reload that version of the App into your library and move the file back into the Mobile Applications Directory.
6. Delete the app from your phone, then just sync your phone and the old app should be loaded in. You may need to click on the phone and apps in iTunes and have iTunes add it.

Best of luck on getting the app.

Comment: For some reason the recent version of iTunes don't seem to have an option to sync the apps from the device to the computer, so they don't show up in Mobile Applications.  Do you know how to turn on app sync?

Comment: @Matt You can only do this in iTunes versions <=12.6.3. There are links to iTunes 12.6.3 in [this help article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208079)

Answer (score 2):

If you still use iTunes download the current version of the app to your computer so that you have "ownership".

Now, on your phone, go to the App Store and attempt to download from the cloud. You will be told that this version is not compatible and be offered an older version. Accept the offer and you will have a working version on your phone.
Don't forget to backup when you are done.

Answer (score 2):

I just did this with the Phillips Hue app (compatible 8.0+) and using iOS 7.0.4. Basically, you download the app from the App Store in your computer. Then, find the app on your phone and instead of Get+ it should display the Cloud download. If the app has an older compatible version available, you should be able to install it. It worked for me!

Comment: Could you be more verbose for "download the app"? I have only "+Get" button in AppStore, and when I press it, I get the message that I need to upgrade to 8.0.

Comment: "App Store on your computer" ... perhaps he means "iTunes on your computer".

Answer (score 2):

3uTools from [www.3u.com](https://www.3u.com) allows you to add iOS apps to your iCloud apple account, so that it appears in your purchase history so you can download it on an old iOS version.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is not easy given, because if you follow the above Apple instruction, the ipa file would also be in the purchased list of the Appstore...
In Mac iTunes 12.3.1 in **my** ElCapitan all (old and new) are in the same folder "Mobile Applications" folder, but each app the latest version that was once installed.