# How to install new Netflix on old iPad?

Tags: ipad, netflix

I have a 32GB iPad 1 that I have had running for about six years. Recently, there was a virus and I had to reset it. I did so successfully. It has iOS 5.1.1 (9B206) installed.

In General > Software Update I see "iOS 5.1.1 Your software is up to date".

When I go to the App Store and try to install Netflix, I am informed that "this application requires iOS 9.0 or later". Obviously, I can't do so.

Is there a way to install ANY version of Netflix on my iPad?

Answer (score 1):

What version of Netflix is stored with your iTunes Library on your Mac/PC? You could check this to see whether you still have the old version:

- **If so:** you can select and sync the Netflix app from your iTunes library to your iPad.
- **If not, and you have a Mac:** Your Time Machine backup should have backups of all the apps previously downloaded/synced with your iPad. These will be located within your iTunes Library. So you could go back far enough to find a version of the Netflix app that will work with your iPad and restore that version to your iTunes Library. Then select and sync that version to your iPad from within iTunes.
- **If not, and you have a PC:** Assuming you have past backups of your iTunes Library, you can do the same as above (i.e. copy back a version of the Netflix app that will work with your iPad to your iTunes Library. Then select and sync that version to your iPad from within iTunes.

Comment: I did not have Netflix in my iTunes Library. I just added the latest version to my library. I wasn't backing up my iPad. I used it SOLELY for Netflix. Now it seems my perfectly working iPad is perfectly useless. (I wonder if Steve Jobs saw that coming.)

Comment: You wonder if Steve Jobs envisioned that you wouldn't be able to run the latest version of an application, on 7 year old hardware and a 6 year old operating system, that you weren't backing up... were you really wondering that?

Comment: I don't want to run the latest version of Netflix. I want to run ANY version of Netflix. Yes, I wonder if Jobs knew that he'd created hardware and software that would run perfectly beyond its usefulness. Of course, the Apple store refuses to provide a version of Netflix that works for his hardware that does work.

Comment: Actually, your assumption that the App Store *refuses to provide a version of Netflix that works for this hardware* isn't correct. Developers (in this case Netflix) decide what versions they keep available. Apple **is** moving to 64-bit apps, but that's not at play in your current scenario. I know for a fact Netflix still provides a version of its app for iOS 7, so in your case they've deemed iOS 5 not to be a priority, probably because only 0.8% of users are still on that version (as at April 2017).

Comment: I solved the issue. I have two iPads, named A and B. I was able to sync the old Netflix app on iPad A to my iTunes Library and then sync that app to iPad B.

Comment: That's great! :) We didn't realise you had it on another iPad. You could choose to provide that process as an answer to the [duplicate](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/195074/how-do-i-install-an-older-version-of-an-app-on-an-iphone) question, as it's something that will be useful to other users.