# How to install an older version app?

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to use my old iPhone 4S as a "software token machine", so I installed and configured all the needed apps in there (and just those ones). It is running iOS v9.3.6.

One app, at its latest version, is refusing to install (SafeNet MobilePass) because my phone doesn't run iOS v10.

Before ditching definitely my plan, is there a way to install an older app version without jailbreaking?

P.S. I only have Linux PCs as it [looks like](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/195074/how-do-i-install-an-older-version-of-an-app-on-an-iphone) a PC could be needed.

Comment: You already seem to have found the previous question on this. Can you explain how yours differs from that?

Comment: Also, you need to have iTunes running if you want to install apps via computer.

Comment: @nohillside My question differs as I don't have a PC that runs iTunes.

Comment: And I am interested into a specific app, not any app.

Comment: The process of installing old versions is the same for all apps, as are the constrains. If you are looking for ways to install apps from Linux, please ask a question specifically for that.